# Generating CRM Proxy classes as separate files

Tags: c#, proxy, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

I have been using and old assembly that references a Dynamics CRM tenant. The assembly contains (among other things) the proxy classes for the tenant. I need to update the proxy classes to the most recent version.

I have used crmsvcutil.exe in the past to generate the proxy class filefor a tenant, but in this assembly the classes each in their own separate files. For example, there is a 'person' c-sharp file which contains the variables of the person entity and the get/set methods.

The current files are in the following format:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
namespace CRM2011.Proxy.Organisation
{
    [GeneratedCode("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.1"), DesignerCategory("code"), DebuggerStepThrough, XmlType(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices")]
    [Serializable]
public class thr_offer : BusinessEntity
{
    private Lookup createdbyField;
    private CrmDateTime createdonField;
    //More variables here
    public Lookup createdby
    {
        get
        {
            return this.createdbyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.createdbyField = value;
        }
    }
    public CrmDateTime createdon
    {
        get
        {
            return this.createdonField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.createdonField = value;
        }
    }
    //More get/set methods here
}
```

These appear to have been generated by a tool, but I don't know of any tool that will do this. If I can generate files such as these instead of the monstrous file generated by crmsvcutil.exe it will make development much easier.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files were generated with the CRM 4.0 SDK (the `CrmDateTime` rang a bell).

With the `CrmSvcUtil.exe` from the CRM 4.0 SDK it is possible to generate separate files, as documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681563.aspx

> /out parameter
>
> Determines the name of the .cs or .xml output file and whether there
>   is one file or one per entity. It may include a full path. If you
>   specify a name that does not end with .cs or .xml, CrmSvcUtil will
>   write an individual .cs file for every entity in the system to the
>   folder you specify. For example, /out:MyClasses outputs a class file
>   (.cs) for every entity to a folder called MyClasses.However,
>   /out:MyClasses.cs outputs a class file (MyClasses.cs) that contains
>   all entities.

This "feature" has been removed from CRM 2011 SDK (if you try to specify the name without the file extension it will still generate a single file)

Answer (score 1):

You'd either have to create a splicer that splices the entities for you after they've been generated into a single file, or create CrmSvcUtil extensions that perform this basic change of behavior for you.

*Edit* Which the Early Bound Generator in the [XrmToolBox](https://www.XrmToolBox.com) does via configuration.

Answer (score 0):

CrmSvcUtil contained in [Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreTools 9.1.0.108](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreTools) support splitting entities (and other types) into single files using commandline arguments `/splitfiles` and `/outdirectory`.

*NOTE: The CrmSvcUtil is not 100% clear about the `/splitfiles` argument, as it is referenced as `/SplitToFiles` by itself.*